# How to insert an element at the current position in HTML using prototype

Tags: javascript, html, dom, prototypejs

How do you insert an HTML element dynamically (using prototype) at the *current* position if you don't know the id of the parent element? All examples I've seen assumes the element has some kind of id.

I.e.

```
<script>
    function addSomeHtmlAtCurrentPosition()
    {
        current_element = ...; // Magic?
        current_element.insert(...);
    }
</script>
<div>
    <script>
        addSomeHtmlAtCurrentPosition();
    </script>
    <!-- should insert something here... -->
</div>
<div>
    <script>
        addSomeHtmlAtCurrentPosition();
    </script>
    <!-- ... and then here -->
</div>
```

I've tried using prototype with $$('div').last(), but that doesn't seem to work (last() sometimes reports back another div if I use libraries such as livepipe).

What I really want is something similar to document.write, but using prototype instead of raw html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I can think of is finding the <script> element and insert the element before/after the script. The thing is, all DOM methods need a DOM node to operate on. Executing scripts that modify the DOM before the document has loaded isn't a good and safe idea.

Similar questions linked below.

1. [JavaScript: get the current executing <script> node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954790/javascript-get-the-current-executing-script-node)
2. [How may I reference the script tag that loaded the currently-executing script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403967/how-may-i-reference-the-script-tag-that-loaded-the-currently-executing-script)

Comment: I see, probably makes sense. Modifying an HTML document on the fly is probably a bad idea. In the end I refactored my HTML/javascript to use prototype css selectors to insert HTML elements dynamically, which actually turned out to be a much cleaner solution.