# Javascript inline HTML

Tags: javascript, html, random

I need to write HTML and Javascript code inline i.e. inside  HTML Body (Need to display some random whole number value) I sought a lot of blogs but found no help so far in doing so. Please advise.

I wanna achieve this functionality:

```
   <td class="vhead">Offered Calls</td>
   <td>
      <script>
       Math.random();
      </script>
  </td>
  </td>
```

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5850477/how-to-insert-an-element-at-the-current-position-in-html-using-prototype

Comment: @Yannjoel: That one would only be confusing.

Comment: if you could use a different file for the javascript, do it. Inline vanilla Javascript is a dirty thing to do most of the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
<td id="demo"></td>

<script>

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Math.random();

</script>
```

Comment: WOw ! :) Tasty , instant , Hot !!!! Fast food. I cant wait 10 minutes to Hit Like. Thanks Mate

Comment: Crowder@ Com on buddy. atleast rate him up. The whole thing is about solution. I found it. kindly accommodate

Comment: Crowder :) :* Love u mate ! :)

Answer (score 0):

for the most simple case

```
<td class="vhead">Offered Calls</td>
<td>
   <script>
      document.write(Math.random());
   </script>
</td>
```

Answer (score -1):

Javascript does not work like this. It can with the help of templating libraries. Instead you will need to get a reference to the place in html you want to inject this random value. The below assumes you will have many and want a different random number in each.

```
<td class="vhead">Offered Calls</td>
<td class="random"></td>

<script>
  window.document.onload = function(){
     var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('random');
     [].forEach.call(elements, function (el) { el.innerHTML( Math.random() ) });
  }
</script>
```