# Browsers bug on document.write

Tags: javascript

I have multiple widgets like this

```
var c2409 = "<div class="products">PRODUCT1 PRODUCT2 PRODUCT4 ...</div>";
document.write(c2409)
```

And I call this

```
<script src="website/getjswidget.aspx?cid=xxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx"></script>
```

Now looks like sometime after I clear the cache, this replace everything in my html and I get a blank page only with this div from my widget.
Any other solutions to replace document.write?

Comment: Can you give us more details? What type of widgets are they? What are they for?

Comment: I use that to export a list of products in html code from a database, so I can use it on multiple domains.

Comment: That's not a bug. Document.write is intended to replace all of the page contents. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice

Comment: it was ok from 2006 untill this year ;)

Comment: as @Reeno pointed out. When the page complete load, execution of `document.write` will override the whole DOM content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is by design.

> The write() method is mostly used for testing: If it is used after an HTML document is fully loaded, it will delete all existing HTML.

[Source](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_write.asp)

If you want to append data to your webpage, use this:

```
document.body.innerHTML += 'your HTML code to add'
```

Edit: If you want to show this in a particular element, you can do something like this:

```
<!-- HTML element -->
<div id="myData"></div>

<!- Javascript code -->
document.getElementById('myData').innerHTML += 'your HTML'
```

Edit 2 (After some searching): You can get the current script element by using [`document.currentScript`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/currentScript) and then perhaps use [`Node.insertBefore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore) to create a div right before that script tag, to put your data in.

Edit 3: Apparently `document.currentScript` doesn't work in IE. But [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2954896/5170231) may help.

Comment: I need this to show after the script not on the end of the body

Comment: You see I can't really add a ID now, beacuse I already use thousands of widgets on websites.

Comment: @Adrian I edited my answer. Unfortunately `document.write` can never be relied on 100% for what you want to do with it, but implementing it like in my answer is a way to always have the html end up where you want it.

Comment: @Adrian see my second edit, perhaps this can help you find a solution?

Comment: can't use that beacuse I already use thousands of widgets on websites. So I need a way to fix this from same script :(

Comment: My second solution, retrieving the current script element and adding a HTML element next to it, would work from your existing script without having to manipulate the external website. See my latest edit for IE compatibility though.

Comment: thanks for this, but I need IE support too. Also looks like Opera and more mobile phone are not suporting this. That fix for IE is ok when you use only 1 single script on page, but I have more

Comment: @Adrian you'd have to go through the script tags and find the one that loads your script, for example by matching the `src` attribute. Afaik there are no 'simple' options that can replace `document.write`.

Comment: yes I think this is the only real solution. thank you!